# What are the strongest wire connection points on flexible PCB

Tags: pcb, connector, wire, flexible

Wires have to be soldered onto the bottom pads, however these pads are really fragile and often get loose from the flexible PCB. Now I'm trying to create these PCBS myself but with different connection points on the bottom. If I have to connect wires to a flexible PCB, what is going to be the strongest, least fragile method for this? So which connection points should I add which won't let go of the PCB that easily?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The thing that makes connections less fragile is called strain relief. In simple terms this means the wire should not move once it is soldered. Strain relief can be provided in a number of ways, you can use adhesive, tape, zip ties, heat shrink or connectors to provide strain relief.

If I were soldering wires to this flex myself I would use a through hole for soldering and then have some means of fastening down the wire, either kapton tape or adhesive. If you put a stiffener on the flex a zip tie could possibly be used.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to design a small rigid PCB to match the lower section.  Stack both on top of each other and solder.  This gives it stiffness, and if mounting holes are included on the PCB, a way to secure it.